# Invalid template parameter property 'numRetries' in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am working on a cloudformation template and have several SNS subscriptions I am trying to add. (I am also somewhat of a noob at this)  There is a block of parameters that repeat for all of them.  I tried to add it to the parameters block but I am getting Invalid template parameter property 'numRetries'.  I am using YAML as well.

```
methodUpdateSubscription:
   Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
   Properties:
      Endpoint: <my email>
      Protocol: email
      DeliveryPolicy:
         healthyRetryPolicy: !Ref 'healthyRetryPolicy'
      TopicArn: !Ref 'methodUpdate'
```

Here are the parameters I want to use:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  lambdaCodeBucket:
    Type: 'String'
  healthyRetryPolicy:
     numRetries: 20
     minDelayTarget: 10
     maxDelayTarget: 30
     numMinDelayRetries: 3
     numMaxDelayRetries: 17
     numNoDelayRetries: 0
     backoffFunction: exponential
```

From other looking around I have done, I guess I can't just add that block to the parameters area and have it work.  It does work when it is in each SNS topic.

Is there any other way I can add that in as a variable or something?

Also, I didn't copy and paste so if there are any spelling or other errors like that, it isn't that way in the code.  :)

Comment: Can you show where exacty are you using `healthyRetryPolicy`, where is it defined?

Comment: In this example it is one of the parameters at the beginning of the YAML file in the Parameters setup.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your `healthyRetryPolicy` parameter is incorrect. There is no such construct as:

```
Parameters:
  healthyRetryPolicy:
     numRetries: 20
     minDelayTarget: 10
     maxDelayTarget: 30
     numMinDelayRetries: 3
     numMaxDelayRetries: 17
     numNoDelayRetries: 0
     backoffFunction: exponential
```

The [valid parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties) are `String`, `Number`, `List<Number>` and `CommaDelimitedList`, plus [AWS-specific types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types).

You either have to pass them individually, e.g.:

```
Parameters:

  numRetries:
     Type: Number
     Default: 20

  minDelayTarget:
     Type: Number
     Default: 10

  # and so on for the rest
```

or through mixture of individual definitions, `List<Number>` or `CommaDelimitedList`.